# protobuf-net extensions : "already contains a definition"

Tags: protobuf-net

I have the following (simplified !) .proto. It's from another software, *I can't modify it*.

```
package test;

message Base
{
    optional string name            = 2;
    extensions 1000 to max;
}

message Extension1 {
  extend Base {
    optional Extension1 type = 1000;
  }
  optional double     blabla      = 2;
}

message Extension2
{
  extend Base {
    optional Extension2 type = 1001;
  }
  optional double     blabla      = 2;
}
```

Compiling if with protogen generates the following C# for the Base message (extract) :

```
private test.Extension1 _type = null;
[global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(1000, IsRequired = false, Name=@"type", DataFormat = global::ProtoBuf.DataFormat.Default)]
[global::System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(null)]
public test.Extension1 type
{
  get { return _type; }
  set { _type = value; }
}

private test.Extension2 _type = null;
[global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(1001, IsRequired = false, Name=@"type", DataFormat = global::ProtoBuf.DataFormat.Default)]
[global::System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(null)]
public test.Extension2 type
{
  get { return _type; }
  set { _type = value; }
}
```

As you can see, the extensions are both called "type", but should be called "Extension1::type" and "Extension2::type" (if my understanding of [extensions](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#extensions) is correct).

Clearly, this doesn't compile. Also, Name=@"type" seems wrong to me (not sure, might be ok).

**What can I do to be able to read files serialized with this .proto ?**

Possible workarounds I've thought of:

- Modifying the .proto and renaming "type" to "type1". This will surely break everything.
- Going through a binary .pb with protoc. Reduces the number of errors, but many remain.
- Patching protogen so that it generates field names like "Extension1_type"
- Hand-patching the .cs with field names like "Extension1_type"
- Using something else than protobuf-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options:

- try protobuf-csharp-port, which is much closer to the google code-base, and might handle this scenario better
- edit the generated C# file to rename one of the members: names are never used in the binary format, so as long as the numbers are the same, the names *don't matter*
- edit the .proto file: for the same reasons above, nothing bad will happen if you simply copy the file, edit the names in the copy, and generate code from the copy

Comment: Thanks. I indeed tried to edit the .proto, but I did not answered my own question because of some other problem. Thanks for confirming that it's a valid workaround.